# LED Blinking with 555 on button press

Tags: led, 555

This may be a simple question, but I couldn't find anything exactly for this.

I wish to implement LED blinking if a button is pressed, and it should continue to blink, unless button is pressed again. Any suggestion on how to achieve this without microcontroller.
Can a 555 be used for something like this?

Comment: Use a latching button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with a [556 timer IC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snas549/snas549.pdf) (dual 555 in a single package), or two 555 ICs.

Use the first "555" of the 556 (or an individual 555) in a bistable multivibrator configuration, as described in simple terms in [this article](http://www.buildcircuit.com/toggle-switch-using-555/) and [this other one](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/articles/555-bistable-multivibrator.291/).

[image: Bistable]

Instead of using the output to drive the LED as shown, feed it to the RST pin of the second 555, which would normally be connected to the supply rail. Configure the second 555 as an [astable multivibrator](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Electronics_Handbook/Components/Multivibrator#Mini-astable) to blink your LED:

[image: Astable]

Each time the pushbutton is pressed, the output pin of the first multivibrator will toggle state, and the blinking output of the second multivibrator will thus start, or stop. No microcontrollers are needed.

I'm too lazy to draw a combined schematic, but the above should serve the purpose.

Comment: I don't know enough to know so I will ask.  Will there be button bouncing problems with this, i.e. could it be the case that the button press bounce would toggle the state of the first 555 multiple times on a  single "press"? If so, how would one address that?

Comment: Yes, there will be, a bit. Debouncing can be improved using either a capacitor and resistor combination, or by using yet another 555 to achieve a debounced bistable, or through a variety of other ways a web search will reveal. Alternatively, it's a worthwhile fresh question to ask. :-)